# Trouble installing from disk

Tags: 11.04, installation

I'm writing this in desperation, Windows is slowly killing me and i need to change my home pc os to Ubuntu 11.04 as soon as possible.

I created a USB flash drive to install ubuntu, twice, and both times they failed to begin install on restart of my pc. i read on another forum that you might have to change some boot sequence in BIOS but when pressing F2 to enter it didnt work.
After a lot of cursing, I made myself an UBUNTU install cd and booted. To my excitement, it now displayed... try ubuntu  and  install ubuntu. i clicked install ubuntu which lead me to the preparing to install ubuntu display, i checked download updates while installing  and clicked forward. The very next display is ' allocate drive space ' i assume there are meant to be options of drives provided but mine is just a blank box and underneath all the options to create a new partition table, add, change, delete and revert are all greyed out. There is a drop down menu labelled 'device for boot loader installlation' but the only option is `/dev/sda`. when i click install, a no root file system error comes up telling me to  please correct from the partitioning menu.

I am extremely  frustrated. please!! can anyone help me...

Comment: What hardware do you have? For some reason it cannot detect your drives. Did you verify the MD5SUM of the ISO you downloaded was correct?

Comment: if you choose the /dev/sda from the drop down button - you should be able then to "add" and add a "/" partition.  Are you saying you cannot select the drive?

Comment: Same here.
Just grayed out buttons all over. The bottom dropdown for bootloader has only /dev/sda in it, but the top is all grayed out and nothing to do.
Pressing install tells me "No root file system is defined." and ok gets you back to the screen again and it flashes "Detecting" etc... Then the list is still empty. I think this is related to the installer failing to list the drives. Can it be due to S.M.A.R.T failure? My disk shows up in disk manager on live disc and it sais it's possibly failing, but on other machines it sais smart is fine and all tests pass.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same Problem when i made the switch to Ubuntu. first partion to create is a swap file So select `/dev/sda` then there will be a drop down box that you can add `swap` set that partion to 8000 then "Create" . Then the rest of drive you will need to make it " / " (aka root) then Create partion then try to install from there.